# What's the best way to explicitly include types in tsconfig?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have run into a situation where I want to include some but not all of the @types in my node_modules directory.

**Background**

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

My @types are installed through npm and located in the node_modules dir.

[image]

The compiler is able to find @types because typeRoots is set to node_modules/@types by default.¹ Or at least that's what I think is happening.

**The Problem**

We are using AngularJS, and we have used (stupidly, perhaps) the `module` variable provided by angular-mocks to bootstrap our spec files.

However, @types/node also has a `module`, and it has a different type.

Now whenever I compile my tests, I get an error in every spec file: `Type 'NodeModule' has no compatible call signatures.`

I want to avoid changing every spec file from `module` to `angular.mock.module`. I need to find a way to exclude @types/node.

**The Question**

What's the best way to explicitly include types in the tsconfig?

**Possible Solutions**

Option A: List required types under the `typesRoots` property, and mark "node_modules" as `exclude`. (will this even work?)

Option B: Don't use typeRoots at all. Use `include` and `exclude` to configure the @types I want. (this works)

Option C: Create a dedicated tsconfig for testing, and use option A or option B in the dedicated tsconfig (with extends, perhaps)

---

¹ The [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) say:

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in `node_modules/@types` of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within `./node_modules/@types/`, `../node_modules/@types/`, `../../node_modules/@types/`, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to use the `types` tsconfig property:

```
"types": ["angular", "angular-mocks", ... etc
```

This will stop tsc from automatically enumerating all the folders you have under `node_modules/@types`. You can use config file inheritance if needed so that you can share all the other compiler settings without duplication.

Comment: ah yes, the hidden Option D :)

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Have you guys thought of adding a `excludeTypes: ["foo", "bar"]` property? It would help tremendously in monorepo scenarios, because listing everything manually as you've proposed works but requires more maintenance and hand editing - rather include everything and exclude those types that are undesirable in certain subprojects.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Please take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54822732/exclude-certain-typings-from-subprojects-tsconfig-json) if you have a chance.