# Exclude certain typings from subproject's tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

I have a single project with a node/express subproject and an angular subproject. There is a base `tsconfig.json`, and one for each subproject (which use `extends` to extend the base file).

```
/tsconfig.json
/src/client/tsconfig.json
/src/server/tsconfig.json
/test/client/tsconfig.json
/test/server/tsconfig.json
```

The problem is that I use Jest (based on Jasmine) for testing the server, and Angular also uses Jasmine for testing. So there are multiple Jasmine-related packages and `@types/foo` packages, and they conflict. So when I compile I get many errors like:

> Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: ...

I solved this by adding to the subprojects' `tsconfig.json` files:

```
types: [
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "baz",
  // ...DOZENS more
]
```

And every time I install a typings package I must remember to add it to the subprojects. It gets messy and *is hard to maintain*.

`tsconfig.json` doesn't have something like a blacklist `excludeTypes` property, which would make this easier (so I could exclude the offending package in a subproject).

So, what is the best way to handle this scenario? Is there a better way than what I'm doing, which avoids managing dozens of typings manually?